# sending sms and email simultaneously What about FB and Twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, email, twitter, sms

Is it possible to have an app send a text message/image to multiple email and sms accounts by pressing a single button? I understand that in the background the emails and sms messages are sent consecutively but I'm trying to avoid multiple view controllers being presented to the user.  I have seen "iOS doesn't allow you to send e-mails or texts without user interaction" but the user would be pressing a button saying it was sending the message to list of email addresses and sms numbers.

I've been reviewing the materials on the Social Framework and MessageUI.Framework and searching forums but cannot find the information I'm looking for. Is there another framework I should be using?

As an extension Can you use the same button to send the same message to multiple accounts such as a facebook and twitter account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FacebookSDK` for Facebook and (for example) `FSHTwitterEngine` for Twitter and create your own custom composer and sender. Both this libraries has sources on GitHub, so you can do what you want. But it not so easy way.

Comment: Thanks. Having asked around, it seems that Apple will not allow you to have one button does it all for email and sms and probably not for FB etc.  Even if you can create it, Apple will not let you sell an app on itunes if it has this feature.  I think Apple wants to protect users from sending out mass messages in case a program tries to send out spam without the user knowing.